# pageMod attaching workers multiple times

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have encountered this issue while working on an extension.  I am attaching a pageMod to the page based on tab ready event to modify the contents of the page, but when I reload the page, the worker seems to get attached one more time, so after 1 reload it loads 2 workers for the same url (no iframes), after 2 reloads it loads 3 workers, etc.  Here's the initial code that I started with (I ripped it out of the larger block):

```
mod = null;   

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {    
    mod = this.pageMod.PageMod({
        include: ["*"],
        contentScriptFile: ["resource://data/full_page.js"],
        attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            Logger.log('---------> worker.url is ' + worker.url);
        }
    });
}
```

I was able to remedy this somewhat by destroying the mod on every ready event by attaching this code at the very beginning of the ready event handler.

```
mod = null;   

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    if (mod) {
        mod.destroy();
    }

    mod = this.pageMod.PageMod({
        include: ["*"],
        contentScriptFile: ["resource://data/full_page.js"],
        attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            Logger.log('---------> worker.url is ' + worker.url);
        }
    });
}
```

However, I still see that two workers get attached after the first reload, three after the second, etc. I made sure my listener got initialized only once. Anybody encountered this before?  Am I not using it correctly?
Thanks!
Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not using it correctly. A pagemod only needs to be set up once. It automatically attaches on ready. The page mod you created is going attach to every new page (`["*"]`). And every time a new page loads, a new pagemod is created that attaches to every new tab...

If you want to insert a content script into every page, just get rid of the on ready listener.

```
    mod = this.pageMod.PageMod({
        include: ["*"],
        contentScriptFile: ["./full_page.js"],
        attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            Logger.log('---------> worker.url is ' + worker.url);
        }
    });
```

If you want to use the on ready listener for a specific tab, [attach a script to the tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Run_scripts_in_a_tab):

```
tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {    
    var worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: ["./full_page.js"]
    });
    Logger.log('---------> worker.url is ' + worker.url);
}
```